# How to create a Timer in J2ME or LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, timer, lwuit

I want to change incrementally every 5 milliseconds the backgroundTransparency of a LWUIT Button when it has focus. So I thought about timer , but I do not find any timer class in either J2ME or LWUIT Javadoc. So how to create timer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J2ME have timer class see [this](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/timer-midlet.shtml) example

Answer (score 4):

Use the timertask class provided by J2ME, i creates a thread and you can repaint after the time is elapsed. It kind of works like the setTimeout in javascript.

```
Timer aTimer = new Timer();
            TimerTask ttask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    checkInternet();
                }
            };
            aTimer.schedule(ttask, 1000);
```

Comment: It's could to be an other argument number for e.g. `aTimer.schedule(ttask,100, 100);`